# m2e installed but not showing in the list in Ubuntu Juno

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I've installed m2e in Juno via the Eclipse Marketplace and adding the M2E repository and both of them install with no problems.

M2E is shown in the "installed software" list.

However, I have no Maven option in the `New Project` menu or the `Import` menu.

Am I missing something? It works perfectly with Helios.

I'm running Eclipse Juno for J2EE and Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: Have you installed maven on your machine (outside of Eclipse)? Does maven show up in the preferences page?

Comment: Hi, yes, Maven is installed and working from the console. I've Indigo installed and the m2e plugin works. However, in Juno there is no clue for the plugin. Not in 'Preferences' nor in 'New Project' menu

Comment: OK. Check the installed plugins (Window -> Show View -> Plugin Repository) to confirm that m2e is listed there.  Also Show the Error Log to see if any errors were thrown on startup (You might not have the right level of m2e for Juno, for example).  Finally, if all else fails, check the .log file in the .metadata directory in your workspace root directory to see if there are any errors.  You can delete .log and restart Eclipse to make the log easier to view.

Comment: Done all this myself and still doesn't work.  Sometimes installing a fresh instance of Eclipse is your only option.  p2 can get corrupt, and while it reports that you have a plugin installed, and you can find it in your Eclipse installation, it's just not active in Eclipse.  The logs don't show anything the matter either.

Comment: Yep, just keep using Indigo ;D Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is that the workspace is locked, so you cannot install plugins.

Try the following methods:

```
rm ~/workspace/.metadata/.lock

sudo gedit /opt/eclipse/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs

sudo chown -R user_name:user_name /home/kate/workspace
```

Answer (score 1):

I just migrate eclipse from indigo to juno version and I had the same problem.

I removed the content of ~/.eclipse (that contained data of eclipse indigo), 
I deleted the .metadata/.lock 
and I install again the m2e and m2e-wtp.

Now it works, I have the Maven option in the click-right menu, in the preferences, and in the import menu.